NodeJS String.indexOf slowness even though index 200/1000000
Consider a long stringified JSON object (millions of characters) returned by an API.
Since I just need to find some value based on its key, my first reflex was to parse it and then select it directly, but I figured out it was too painfully slow (40ms).
Since the key I am looking for is unique across all properties and is located at the beginning (around index 200), I tried to work around it by using indexOf("key":") and then get the value myself using the following function, but this ALSO runs slow in NodeJS (40ms) whereas it takes 0.08ms in the browser, and I don't understand why :
const indexOf = (string, substring, stringStartIndex=0) => {
    const stringLastIndex = string.length - substring.length
    loop:
    for(; stringStartIndex <= stringLastIndex; stringStartIndex++){
        for(let substringIndex = 0; substringIndex < substring.length; substringIndex++){
            if(string[stringStartIndex + substringIndex] !== substring[substringIndex]){
                continue loop
            }
        }
        return stringStartIndex
    }
    return -1
}

const key = `"key":"`
console.time("indexOf call")
const keyStartIndex = indexOf(string, key) + key.length
console.timeEnd("indexOf call") // 40.219ms

This makes no sense to me, does anybody knows what happens here?
I am running NodeJS v20.11.0 on a Windows 10 Pro Edition 64--bit computer with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz (3.41 GHz) and 16.0 GB installed RAM (15.9 GB usable)
EDIT2: After some addditional testing I figured out both my custom indexOf function and the native String.indexOf function appear to take almost the same time to complete, but only the first call takes significantly longer. Here's an example :
console.time("String.indexOf call")
string.indexOf(key) + key.length
console.timeEnd("String.indexOf call") // 39.581ms

console.time("custom indexOf call")
indexOf(string, key) + key.length
console.timeEnd("custom indexOf call") // 0.092ms

Or :
console.time("custom indexOf call")
indexOf(string, key) + key.length
console.timeEnd("custom indexOf call") // 37.879ms

console.time("String.indexOf call")
string.indexOf(key) + key.length
console.timeEnd("String.indexOf call") // 0.021ms


What is the host processor and operating system as those times seem extremely slow? I would cut the logic out and put it into something completely separate.  I'm willing to bet that something else is causing the problem.  Test it in isolation and see if the results improve.

Please consider sharing the code you tested and environment / run-time details.

Maybe this is because Node implementation use dichotomic search logic and doesn't browse the word from beginning to end? Anyways l don't want to waste your time nor mine, so I just wrote a small function that doesn't rely on String.indexOf but still, I was always told that premature optimization is the root of all evil, but if I didn't test I would have sent that to prod and waste time later figuring out where the slowness comes from...

Does this answer your question? Out-of-memory issue when using JSONStream in NodeJS

Ok nevermind I am still facing issues I will edit my question.

You can use any 3rd party JSON streaming parsers, so you don't need to load the whole JSON in the first place.
For example:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json
to parse some initial chunk of data.
A comprehensive list is here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7543#issuecomment-41970902
Some usage example is here: Out-of-memory issue when using JSONStream in NodeJS
